# How to assign JSON Array value into variable in Swift 3.0?

Tags: arrays, json, swift3, xcode8

I have these JSON value that generated using PHP mysqli.

```
 {"valid":"1","name":"NAME 1","dept":"IT"}
 {"valid":"1","name":"NAME 2","dept":"IT"}
 {"valid":"1","name":"NAME 3","dept":"PSD"}
 {"valid":"1","name":"NAME 4","dept":"PSD"}
```

But in swift 3.0, I only know to declared an array value manually as below in x code.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet var divisionLbl: UITextField!

    var division = ["IT","FAD","PSD"]

    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad() 
    }
}
```

My goal is to retrieve the JSON value and assign it into variable.

Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code How you are making API request and how you are getting this JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the JSONSerialization class' jsonObject(with:options:) method.

```
class func jsonObject(with data: Data, options opt: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = []) throws -> Any
```

Assuming you already have the JSON Data object, something like this should work:

```
// data = your JSON data

do {
    var assignedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
    // continue...
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
    // Handle exception
}
```

Comment: can i declare the variable outside the do statement ?

Comment: @Jamilah Yes, you can, but I don't think it makes much sense in this case. If you do that, you'll need to declare it as optional, Any?, and then deal with that everywhere since jsonObject(with:options:) returns an Any. I would just put all your code that deals with the "assignedData" inside the do statement under the try statement.